# SALT Hash Passwords in Visual Studio

Tags: hash, passwords, salt

I know there are many questions on SALT and hashing passwords, but I have yet to find a tutorial to walk me through this in VS using the MVC pattern.

I currently have a DB created with a user table containing three columns:

- userID(PK, int, not null)
- password(varchar(45), not null)
- loginID(varchar(8), null)

The password is saved as a visible string in the DB. After researching the issue, I assume password is easiest as binary instead of varchar. Does anyone know of a good tutorial to implement hashing and SALT into my program? One that clearly defines this in terms of the MVC pattern is preferred.

Comment: The [help/on-topic] very clearly says *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow*.

Answer (score 0):

MVC doesn't have anything to do with salting your passwords, although someone might point to the proper libraries that might be used with your tech stack.

Salting involves using a specific sequence, and appending that to the end of user passwords, and then hashing that data.

The reason this is done is because a hash algorithm applies on a well known string is easily reversible.  A person could, for example, use well known hash algorithms against a whole dictionary, and compare to user passwords to determine what it was hashed from.  While a good hash function is a one way function (aka can't find the input based on the output), if you had a dictionary to map you could easily do it for well known strings/ string combinations.

For example, the password password has a well known hash.  When you attach a random sequence to the end (or start) and then hash that, it's a significantly less common hash as a result, and then it's significantly harder to reverse.

Sorry for not having the specific technologies related, but I wanted to communicate the general higher level concept of it since the over-focus on the technologies loses the bigger picture.

Comment: That makes much more sense knowing it doesn't implicitly use MVC. I didn't how to implement it with that. Any idea of a good tutorial or code example?